# How to fix YoutubeApi error message: preload problem and postMessage

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, youtube-api, vue-cli

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Use Vue-cli to develop multi-page case

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

Test browser version: google chrome  103.0.5060.134 version

dependencies : {
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
"vue-router": "^3.2.0",
}

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

**what happend?**

When npm run serve , and enter website, the error message is like below block
No problem at all, and sometimes the error always occurs when I click cmd+shift+R && F5

> The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before
> 'preloadResponse' settled. If you intend to use 'preloadResponse', use
> waitUntil() or respondWith() to wait for the promise to settle.

In some situations, like click other pages also error messages like below block

> www-widgetapi.js:987 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow':
> The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match
> the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:3000'). ￼

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

[code]
Mounted

```
...
data () {
    return {
      player: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    const tag = document.createElement('script')
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'
    const getHead = document.getElementsByTagName('Head')[0]
    getHead.append(tag)

    // when first init youtubeapi
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
      this.initYoutube(this.$refs.player)
    }
    // when again into the page
    this.initYoutube(this.$refs.player)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    // when leave the page will destory this player 
    if (this.player !== null && this.player.destroy) {
      this.player.destroy()
      delete this.player
    }
  },
```

Methods

```
methods: {
    initYoutube () {
      if (!window.YT) return
      this.player = new window.YT.Player('player', {
        height: '1080',
        width: '1920',
        videoId: 'HDx8Z-XB7A4',
        playerVars: {
          autoplay: 1,
          controls: 0,
          disablekb: 1,
          fs: 0,
          iv_load_policy: 3,
          loop: 1,
          modestbranding: 0,
          rel: 0,
          playsinline: 1,
          playlist: 'HDx8Z-XB7A4',
          origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // It's look didn't work 
          host: 'https://www.youtube.com'// It's look didn't work
        },
        events: {
          onReady: this.onPlayerReady,
          onStateChange: this.onPlayerStateChange
        }
      })
    },
    onPlayerReady (evt) {
     // loop the video
      evt.target.mute()
      evt.target.playVideo()
    },
    onPlayerStateChange (evt) {
     // loop the video
      if (evt.data === 0) {
        evt.target.playVideo()
      }
    }
...
}
```